# How does WordPress resolve public URL to pages?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to understand how the URL resolution happens in WordPress. When a page is created/edited the internal link is something like the following:

```
example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=165&action=edit
```

But to view the page, the URL used is something like the following:

```
example.com/about-us
```

How does WP resolve the public URL and generate the page?

Comment: Each page has a `slug`. In Settings > Permalinks, you can select the display style (post name, numeric, day and name, custom structure, etc.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to see how WordPress programmatically resolve the URL.

Comment: I mean... if what you truly want to know is "*how WordPress programatically [resolves] the URL*", it's open source software - just review the source code...?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [How does routing on wordpress work?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141072/how-does-routing-on-wordpress-work/141087#141087)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell WordPress does this resolution using the .htaccess file.  The rules are set in .htaccess to route the request to an index.php file which does the rest of the processing to generate the page.

This is specific to Apache.  Other web servers may do it differently.